Communicate between two RPi Pico by using AP mode
I'm building a robot with two Pico Ws. One in the remote control, and one in the robot. I want to use asynchronous code to allow the remote control to collect button states and display info while sending the button states. This code worked when using a router, but when I try to setup the remote control as a server in AP mode, the client Pico might receive data for one or multiple seconds, but then they no longer communicate with each other.
The Remote Control Server code
///micropython///

import asyncio
import time
import network
import machine
from machine import Pin

ssid='NAME'
password='PASSWORD'
led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
async def connect_wlan():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF) #changed from STA_IF
    wlan.config(essid=ssid, password=password)
    wlan.active(True)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:  #changed from wlan.isconnected()
        print('Activating WLAN') 
        await asyncio.sleep(1) 
    print(f'Broadcasting on' , wlan.ifconfig())  

async def phoneback(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print(f"Conenction from {addr!r}")    
    client_data = await reader.read(1024)
    print(f"Client data: {client_data}")   
    response = str("response")
    print(f"sending {response}")
    writer.write(response.encode())
    await writer.drain()  
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
        
async def main():
    await connect_wlan()
    server = await asyncio.start_server(phoneback, '0.0.0.0', 80)
    async with server:
        while True:
            led.toggle()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(main())


The Robot Client code
///micropython///

import asyncio
import time
import network
from machine import Pin
import gc

ssid='NAME'
password='PASSWORD'

async def connect_wlan():
    sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    sta_if.active(True)
    sta_if.connect(ssid, password)
    while sta_if.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return sta_if

def log(*args, **kwargs):
    print(f"{time.time():.1}", *args, **kwargs)

async def get_data():
    """Periodic network task"""
    while True:
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("8.8.8.8", 80)
        log(f"Connected!")
        try:
            writer.write("Client_Name".encode())
            await writer.drain()
            log(f"Request Sent!")
            ss = str(await reader.read(1024))
            print(f"Received Data: {ss}")
            print()
            await asyncio.sleep_ms(200)
            gc.collect()
        except:        
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            gc.collect()
            log(f"Disconnected!")
            await asyncio.sleep(.2)


async def main():
    sta_if = await connect_wlan()
    tasks = []
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(get_data()),
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

while True:
    asyncio.run(main())

I expected the Picos to connect and display the reader, writer data. They seem to connect, but do not display the info.

You have gone to a lot of trouble to put print and logging statements into your client.  What do you see?  If nothing else, you should see "Connected!" about 5 times a second (ignoring the overhead of communication).  Do you?

The client: 1723473780 Connected!
1723473780 Request Sent!
1723473810 Disconnected!
1723473810 Connected!
1723473810 Request Sent!
1723473840 Disconnected!
1723473840 Connected!
1723473840 Request Sent!
1723473870 Disconnected!

So your client never receives any data from the server.  The reader.read() function apparently raises an exception after 30 seconds, almost certainly a timeout error.  If you print the traceback in the except: block you could confirm this.  It seems like your two devices are not communicating at all.  I notice that your client is trying to connect to address 8.8.8.8 and your server is listening on 0.0.0.0.  Perhaps you could check your network parameters.

Also I don't understand why you have said that the client "might receive data for one or multiple seconds" since your log does not contain the words "Received data".
